# ImportError: cannot import name 'TfidVectorizer' in anaconda

Tags: scikit-learn, anaconda

Can't import `multinomialNB` and `make_pipeline` from `sklearn.naive_bayes` and `sklearn.pipeline` respectively, screenshot is attached.I'm using python3. I uninstalled and installed anaconda from "https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/install/index.html" last time.

I installed and uninstalled from separate sources too.

[image]

I tried installing packages separately also. sklearn,scipy or other packages are installed and upgraded but this piece of code is giving the same error again and again.

I tried every possible solutions on internet and stackoverflow.

```
#importing necessary packages
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import multinomialNB
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

#creating a model based on multinomial naive-bayes
model = make_pipeline(TfidVectorizer(), multinomialNB())

#training the model with train data
model.fit(train.data, train.target)

#creating labels for test data
labels = model.predict(test.data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some spelling mistakes in your imports. Also, include the error messages the next time you have an error.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer # notice the spelling with the f before Vectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB # notice the Caps on the M
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
```

EDIT: Also, please [read this about a minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it will make your life a lot easier when trying to get answers from SO in the future.

Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thank you very much ivan :)